# Does React automatically prune components which have had their mount points removed from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For instance, if I use renderComponent to render to a DOM node, then delete the DOM node manually, did I just leak memory? Is the React component which was rendered to the deleted DOM node pruned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably leaked memory. Use `React.unmountComponentAtNode(node)`

Comment: I made a fiddle and it seems to not allocate extra memory on the heap after running it: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/5397/

I don't know why though.

Comment: Paul is right, those components remain in the shadow dom. Good way to inspect this is by downloading the react chrome tools addon which lets you inspect the react shadow dom within the chrome developer tools.  You'll notice that if you just remove dom elements rather than calling `React.unmountComponentAtNode` then these shadow dom representations never get cleaned up.