# React and real DOM cooperation in LeafletJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use React with the `leafletjs` library for maps and I am not sure how to implement this best.

I know that there is a `react-leaflet` github project out there, but in my case I need to use the raw (javaScript) `leafletjs` library (in order to use more unsupported features, such as the divIcon that supports html on the Marker: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon)

The following code that I wrote is definitely not the React way (as it removes and unmounts everything and then recreates and mounts everything) but it works (after many hours of trial and error).

I have around 300 Markers (cars) on the map and with different criteria I hide some of them. I also retrieve slightly updated data from the server.

The problem is that before I use the `unmountComponentAtNode` method, the React devtools showed that 300 components were added on each rerender. So, I had 3000 components at some time and growing, despite their underlying (real DOM) DIVs where deleted by the window.map.carsLayerGroup.clearLayers(); method.

So:

1. Shouldn't the removal of the DOM "DIVs" (by an external library) also automatically "unmount" the related mounted components? Is there a way to do so?
2. If not, is there a way to unmount all 300+ Car components alltogether without looping? For example, something like React.unmountComponents("Car"). Because my loop is not full-proof: when I retrieve new data, some old items will still remain mounted because they do not appear in the new list that will be looped for unmounting.
3. Any ideas on how to approach this? The (non-react) DOM DIV per Marker needs to exist, so I need to find a way for the React component to be rendered there and use the React lifecycles without having to unmount it and recreate it on every rerender.

Thank you!

```
componentWillUpdate() {

const {props, state} = this;
const {cars} = props;


cars.map((car,i) => {     //Clean the previous React components
  try {
    React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById(`s${car.id}`));
  }
  catch (e) {
    //do nothing, continue execution
  }});

  window.map.carsLayerGroup.clearLayers();

  cars.map((car,i) => {
     var myIcon = L.divIcon({
      //className: '',
      iconSize: [24, 24],
      html: `<div id="s${car.id}"></div>`,
    });
    var ang = 45;
    var lat = car.lat+0.02220,
        lon =  car.lon+0.02220;
    var marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: myIcon});
    window.map.carsLayerGroup.addLayer(marker);

    if (myData.filters[`checkCarsOfType${car.type}`])
      React.render(<Car key={car.id} car={car} carIndex={i} {...props}/>,document.getElementById(`${car.id}`));
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the removal of the DOM "DIVs" (by an external library) also automatically "unmount" the related mounted components? Is there a way to do so?

It [looks like the answer is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795988/does-react-automatically-prune-components-which-have-had-their-mount-points-remo). I know of no way to automate this other than monitoring and checking the DOM nodes yourself.

> If not, is there a way to unmount all 300+ Car components alltogether without looping? For example, something like React.unmountComponents("Car").

I don't believe so, but my answer to the next question may address this problem.

> Any ideas on how to approach this? The (non-react) DOM DIV per Marker needs to exist, so I need to find a way for the React component to be rendered there and use the React lifecycles without having to unmount it and recreate it on every rerender.

As [Ryan Florence](https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/602105296366936064) is [keen](https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/602151298780135424) on [pointing out](https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/601969728345608193), you can model pretty much any kind of nested, tree-like data with React using components. Let's see what the component you pasted code from might look like in this case. (Note I'm making a few assumptions here for the sake of the pseudocode; also note I'm not very familiar with the Leaflet API :)

```
class MyLeafletMapApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <CarMap cars={arrayOfCarsFromSomewhere} />
  }
}

class CarMap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <LeafletMap>
      {this.props.cars.map(this.renderCar)}
    <LeafletMap>
  }

  renderCar(car, idx) {
    return <CarIcon key={car.id} index={idx} car={car} />;
  }
}

class LeafletMap extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { mapCreated: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var mapElement = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.map);
    this.map = L.map(mapElement, {...});
    this.setState({mapCreated: true});
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // clean up the map
  }

  render() {
    // make sure each child knows about the map;
    // don't render children until map exists
    var children;
    if (this.state.mapCreated) {
      var map = this.map;
      children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
        return child ? React.cloneElement(child, {map: map}) : null;
      });
    } else {
      children = null;
    }
    return <div ref="map">{children}</div>;
  }
}

class CarIcon extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      divIconHtml: React.renderToStaticMarkup(
        <Car car={this.props.car} carIndex={this.props.index}
      )
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createMarker();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.map.removeLayer(this.marker);
  }

  createMarker() {
    if (this.marker) {
      this.props.map.removeLayer(this.marker);
    }

    this.icon = L.divIcon({
      iconSize: [24, 24],
      html: React.renderToString(
        <Car car={this.props.car} carIndex={this.props.index} />
      )
    });
    this.marker = L.marker(this.getLatLng(), {icon: this.icon});
    this.props.map.addLayer(this.marker);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // `carIsDifferent` not implemented in this example
    if (carIsDifferent(nextProps.car, this.props.car) {
      this.setState({
        divIconHtml: React.renderToStaticMarkup(
          <Car car={nextProps.car} carIndex={nextProps.index} />
        )
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.divIconHtml !== this.state.divIconHtml) {
      // If the HTML changed, we need to recreate the marker.
      this.createMarker();
    } else {
      // otherwise, we can keep the same marker, just move it
      this.marker.setLatLng(this.getLatLng());
    }
  }

  getLatLng() {
    return [ ... ];
  }

  render() {
    return null; // don't render anything, we attach to the map
  }
}
```

Again, this is pretty pseudocode-y, but hopefully gets the point across. By describing your map as a tree of components, letting React decide when those components appear/change/disappear, and hooking into the appropriate lifecycle hooks, we can remove a lot of the tedious DOM management, looping, and re-creating DivIcons for no reason (when nothing has changed).

The complexity mostly lives in `CarIcon`; this is, as you're aware, because Leaflet DivIcons can only contain static HTML. So, we watch for the car to change, and when it does, recreate the HTML using `renderToStaticMarkup`.

It should be noted that [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) seems to do the same thing for [`Popup` components](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet#technical-considerations):

> `<Popup>` contents are rendered by Leaflet calling `React.renderToStaticMarkup()`, therefore the rendered components have a different context from their owner.

*However*, after reading through [the section on custom layers in the Leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ilayer), I believe it should be possible to create a layer that wraps a fully stateful React component (e.g. you wouldn't need to render to static HTML). Implementing such a component would remove the need for the song-and-dance in `componentWillReceiveProps`, etc. in `CarIcon`.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what you mean at the last paragraph though. I cannot understand how the stateful React Component can approach the divIcon mutation issues, etc.

Comment: @user2078023 The only *built in* layer that supports that kind of custom markup is `divIcon`, and cannot be mutated, but I believe one could create a *custom* leaflet layer that wraps a stateful React component with changing DOM.